# Does two languages use the same stack and heap on the ram?

Tags: java, python, memory-management, stack, heap-memory

I was reading regarding the memory allocation in python and was wondering if I have java and python installed in the same computer system then does java and python use the same stack and heap or they have different stack and heaps allocated for them in the RAM?

Can anyone please help me to clear my doubt.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Every running program has it's on stack and heap. Even two java processes (or two python processes) have their own stack and heap

Comment: @ThomasKläger: Are you sure? What is the heap for a CPython process?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm sure: [the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html) says "Memory management in Python involves a private heap containing all Python objects and data structures"

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is an implementation detail, each *thread* on a system has its own stack. The heap is an image from the 70's segmented model and has no sense on any process except Java ones on a modern OS: when a process requires more memory it just asks the kernel for it and has no preallocated heap. In a sense all processes in a system (except for Java ones) share the same available memory pool, but it not what was called a heap.

Java is different, because a Java program executes in a JVM, and the JVM has its allocated memory and the process cannot require memory from the system. So in a JVM, the whole process has a heap, and each thread has a stack. And if you launch 2 independant Java programs, you will have 2 independant JVM each with its own heap.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really helpful

Comment: This is not an implementation detail, having its own stack is a characteristic of a thread. Further, heap is not an outdated concept, basically every programming language has it and how it maps to OS system calls, often is an implementation detail; it would be disastrous for the performance if every tiny allocation led to such a system call into the kernel. That’s not how programming languages work.

Comment: @Holger: What I mean is that except for Java, there is no longer a preallocated and *contiguous* heap. Of course the dynamic allocation system does cache the allocation calls and can keep a private list of available blocks. But the OS is not required to return allocated block from a contiguous memory zone.

Comment: Java doesn’t require a preallocated contiguous heap either. That’s a property of the widespread HotSpot JVM but even this specific implementation supports shrinking and growing the heap. Mentioning Java’s heap and the 70’s concept in one sentence, is misleading. Other languages use the term *heap memory* as well, but it’s different to Java. Java’s specification just defines heap memory as a) shared (opposed to the stack memory which, unlike C’s stack memory, can never be shared between threads), b) the memory where all objects are allocated, and c) garbage collected. That’s all it mandates.

Comment: @Holger not only that, but the contiguous property is for _virtual_ address space, so, in the 64bit world - who cares?

Comment: The JVM _uncomitts_ already committed pages when it can do that ( this depends on the GC and initial flags ). By far, not everything that is reserved via `Xms` or `Xmx` is committed, usually.

Answer (score 0):

Two different programs *never* use the same heap. They each, get a portion of *virtual* address space, that can overlap in numbers somehow, but these are *independent*. When a program actually needs pages to be in RAM - it allocates them, in a lazy fashion, usually by 4KB ( might be bigger ). This is done via a `Page Table`, which is able to map virtual address space to *phisycal* one ( potentially swap too ).

You probably need to understand that you do not require everything, all the time in RAM. Your code can do a little portion, then give that space in RAM to someone else, or even swap out.